# Change pa$$word to pa\$\$word in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `pa$$word`. I want to change this string to **`pa\$\$word`**. This must be changed to 2 or more such characters only and not for `pa$word`. The replacement must happen n number of times where n is the number of "$" symbols. For example, `pa$$$$word` becomes `pa\$\$\$\$word` and `pa$$$word` becomes `pa\$\$\$word`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You stated your requirements; but you did not show any code or asked a question.

Comment: Oh, you cannot do that in the current versions of Python.  The creators of Python didn't foresee that such a problem might exist in the future.

Comment: @devnull Why so? It is possible. Please check my answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye Do I need to shout that it was a pun on the lazy question.

Comment: @devnull Aah, I had that doubt, since that comment was from you... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

def replacer(matchobj):
    mat = matchobj.group()
    return "".join(item for items in zip("\\" * len(mat), mat) for item in items)

print re.sub(r"((\$)\2+)", replacer, "pa$$$$word")
# pa\$\$\$\$word

print re.sub(r"((\$)\2+)", replacer, "pa$$$word")
# pa\$\$\$word

print re.sub(r"((\$)\2+)", replacer, "pa$$word")
# pa\$\$word

print re.sub(r"((\$)\2+)", replacer, "pa$word")
# pa$word
```

`((\$)\2+)` - We create two capturing groups here. First one is, the entire match as it is, which can be referred later as `\1`. The second capturing group is a nested one, which captures the string `\$` and referred as `\2`. So, we first match `$` once and make sure that it exists more than once, continuously by `\2+`.

So, when we find a string like that, we call `replacer` function with the matched string and the captured groups. In the `replacer` function, we get the entire matched string with `matchobj.group()` and then we simply interleave that matched string with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the regex you're after is:

```
[$]{2,}
```

which will match 2 or more of the character $

Answer (score -1):

this should help

```
  import re

  result = re.sub("\$", "\\$", yourString)
```

or you can try

```
 str.replace("\$", "\\$")
```